# How to update property in UI using MVVM in routine

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to build some count down counter. The problem is that my solution display only beginning value 10 and last value 1 after 10 sec. Of course, I've implemented the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. Any suggestions for that solution?

```
<Button Content="Generuj"  Command="{Binding ButtonStart}"></Button>
<TextBox  Text="{Binding Counter, Mode=OneWay}"></TextBox>

private void ButtonStartClick(object obj)
{
    for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--)
    {
         System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
         Counter = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Counter has to be a property, has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged. Thread.Sleep(1000); is run from the GUI thread -> this blocks updates to the GUI. You will notice a 10 second sleep and the counter then being set to 0.

Comment: You have started code running from a Button Click.  This code is running on the main (UI thread).  That locks  up the UI until the code is done running.  So the UI cannot update until your code is finished.  That means the UI will not show your property updating until your code has finished running.  To update the UI while your code is running, you need to run your code in a BackgroundWorker or an asynchronous Task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also run Counter in separate Thread

```
Task.Run(() =>
             {
                 for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--)
                 {
                     Counter = i;
                     Thread.Sleep(1000);
                 }
             });
```

Answer (score 3):

With Thread.Sleep you are freezing your GUI. Try using a Timer for your purpose.
A timer will run simultaneously to your GUI thread and thus will not freeze it.
Also you will need to implement the PropertyChanged Event for your counter
Also make sure to set your DataContext

```
    //create a dependency property you can bind to (put into class)
    public int Counter
    {
        get { return (int)this.GetValue(CounterProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(CounterProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CounterProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Counter), typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(default(int)));


    //Create a timer that runs one second and decreases CountDown when elapsed (Put into click event)
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.Interval = 1000;
    t.Elapsed += CountDown;
    t.Start();

    //restart countdown when value greater one (put into class)
    private void CountDown(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (counter > 1)
        {
            (sender as Timer).Start();
        }
        Counter--;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use async await to introduce a lightweight delay.

It's main advantage over a timer is there's no risk of leaving the delegate hooked and running.

In this viewmodel I use mvvmlight, but any implementation of ICommand would do.

```
 …..
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;
namespace wpf_99
{
public class MainWindowViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private int counter =10;

    public int Counter
    {
        get { return counter; }
        set { counter = value; RaisePropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private RelayCommand countDownCommand;
    public RelayCommand CountDownCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return countDownCommand
            ?? (countDownCommand = new RelayCommand(
             async () =>
             {
                 for (int i = 10; i > 0; i--)
                 {
                     await Task.Delay(1000);
                     Counter = i;
                 }
             }
             ));
        }
    }
```

Not much to the view, it binds to Counter, of course:

```
<Grid>
    <StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Counter}"/>
        <Button Content="Count" Command="{Binding CountDownCommand}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```